# Score not incrementing

Tags: javascript

I am programming a simple game in javascript and when the user hovers on the given coordinates it's score increases. My problem is the score does not increment after 1.

```js
var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 150;
var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 150;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = y;
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = x;

 //live tracking of coordinates
$("div.frame").mousemove(function (event) {
    var xco = event.clientX;
    var yco = event.clientY;
    var xcoor = "X co-ords: " + xco;
    var ycoor = "Y co-ords: " + yco;

    document.getElementById("display1").innerHTML = xcoor;
    document.getElementById("display2").innerHTML = ycoor;

    //keeping score 
    if (xco == x && yco == y) {
        count++;
        console.log(count);
        document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = count;
        generate();
    }

    //Generating Co-ordinates     
    function generate() {
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 150;
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 150;

        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = y;
        document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = x;

        function points(x, y) {
            if (xco == x && yco == y) {
                count++;
                console.log(count);
                document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = count;
                generate();
            }
        }

        points(x, y);
    }
})
```

Comment: Declare the variable `count` outside of any functions first.

Comment: can I have the html for tests?

Comment: https://ideone.com/jZ1HHs Here is the link for the entire code https://ideone.com/aQv7yc and this is the stylesheet

Comment: are you forgot semi-colon at the end or this is only here?

Comment: please put your html code for trace. thank you.

Comment: https://ideone.com/jZ1HHs here you go.. https://ideone.com/aQv7yc-stylesheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even after adding a global `count` variable, your code is not working properly because of your `if (xco == x && yco == y)` condition fails after first run. Here you are comparing randomly generated `x` and `y` with `xco`, `yco` and updating score and calling generate again.

On your `generate` function you are creating new local variable `x` and `y`, not updating the global `x` and `y`. And the subsequent comparison `(xco == x && yco == y)` will fail because it still using the old `x` and `y`.

On your generate function, updating the global x and y should fix this issue,

```
x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 150;
y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 150;
```

Here is the complete code, I also made some minor changes, removed some redundant and duplicate codes

```js
// Code goes here
    $(document).ready(function(){
      
    //on clicking let's play
    var t = 120;    
    var count = 0;    
    
    $("button.play").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".fadeout").fadeOut(2000, function(){
            $(".heading").text("Click on the Start button when you're ready");
        });
        $(".hidden").attr("hidden", false);
        });
    function start(){
      
      //init game timer
    var Timer = setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById("time1").innerHTML = t;
        --t;
    if(t < 0){
        clearInterval(Timer);
        document.getElementById("timeout").innerHTML = "Time's Up |";
        $("div.frame").attr("hidden",true);
    }
    },1000);

    var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*500)+150;
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*500)+150;
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = y;
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = x;
        
    //live tracking of coordinates
     $("div.frame").mousemove(function(event){
        var xco = event.clientX;
        var yco = event.clientY;
        var xcoor = "X co-ords: " + xco;
        var ycoor =  "Y co-ords: " + yco;
        document.getElementById("display1").innerHTML = xcoor;
        document.getElementById("display2").innerHTML = ycoor;
        //keeping score 
        points(xco, yco);
     })
    $("div.frame").mouseout(function(event){
       document.getElementById("display1").innerHTML = " ";
       document.getElementById("display2").innerHTML = " "; 
    })
    //Generating Co-ordinates     
    function generate(){    
      x = Math.floor(Math.random()*500) + 150;
      y = Math.floor(Math.random()*500) + 150;
      document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = y;
      document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = x;
    }
    function points(xco, yco){
      if(x == xco && y == yco){     
        count++;
        console.log(count);
        document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = count;
        generate();
     }  
    }
    
    }
     $("button.start").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
         start();
         $(this).fadeOut(1500);
         $(this).attr("disabled",true);
         $(".afterstart").fadeOut(1500);
        });
 
    });
```

```css
/* Styles go here */
   body{
        height: 1200px;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    .jumbotron{
        margin-top: 250px;
        padding: 20px;
        height: 350px;
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }
    .heading{
       font-size: 30px;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
    .frame{
        height: 1000px;
        width: 1500px;
        border: 10px solid black;
    }
    ul {
    background: #40475A;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    }
    .stats{
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: 80px;
    }
    .info{
     font-size: 30px;
        color:aliceblue;
    }
.bold{
    font-size: 25px;
    color:antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Irritate</title>
</head>
 
<body>
    <div>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills pl-5 fixed-top d-flex justify-content-center" style="font-size: 25px">
 
        <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" id="display1"></a>
        </li>
 
        <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="display2"></a>
        </li>
 
        </ul>
 
    </div>

 
   <div class="jumbotron fadeout">
       <div class="display-3 text-muted d-flex justify-content-center"> Hand-Job </div>
        <p class="info"> All you have to do is try to match the co-ordinates that will display on the screen </p>
        <p class="bold"><kbd>PS:</kbd>This game will test your patience</p>
         <form>
          <div class="input-group w-75">
 
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                       <span class="input-group-text">Name:</span>
                </div>
 
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="">
 
                <div class="input-group-append">
                           <button class="btn btn-outline-success play">Let's Play</button>
                </div>
          </div>
       </form>
   </div>
   <div class="hidden" hidden="true">
   <div>
       <p class="text-danger heading  afterstart"></p>
   <button class="btn btn-danger w-25 start">Start</button>
    <div  class="d-flex d-flex-inline stats">
 
    <p class="ml-3">X Co-ordinate:<span id="demo1" class="ml-2"></span><span> | </span></p>
    <p class="ml-3">Y Co-ordinate:<span id="demo2" class="ml-2"></span><span> | </span></p>
 
    <p class="ml-3">Time Left:<span id="time1" class="ml-2"></span> <span> | </span></p>
    <p id="timeout" class="ml-3"></p>
    <p>Score: <span id="score"></span></p>    
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="frame ml-2">
   </div>
   <p id="result"></p>
   </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
 
</html>
```

Here is plunker url for the above code https://plnkr.co/edit/7ia7MkMimzlsAxTCWAc9?p=preview

Comment: No man, making mistake is part of learning. I really enjoyed your game, kudos for that. Also, make sure to mark the answer as correct if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

i think its because your `count` variable is local and only live in if block if you want to have count in other place please declare it as global variable

```
var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 150;
var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 150;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = y;
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = x;

var count = 0;

 //live tracking of coordinates
$("div.frame").mousemove(function (event) {
    ...
})
```

Comment: It should be `var count = 0;` to give it global scope.

Comment: Variables "defined" without the [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) (or any of the newer) keyword will be global. _"is local and only live in if block"_ - That would only be true for variables defined with [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) or [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) as these are the only ones with block scope. The scope of variables defined with `var` is their _execution context_.

Comment: Count was already global..it was above the code I posted here please check this link ideone.com/jZ1HHs - this is the html and javascript code ideone.com/aQv7yc and this is the stylesheet